# in Angular Auutocomplete, i am getting previously entered values in suggestion instead of getting values from the array

Tags: angular, angular-material

in my project i have to display address as an autocomplete. i have stored address values in an array and implemented autocomplete.
the values in the array are
address.constant.ts

```
arrOptions = [
"123 seldom st. CA - 91746",
"4533 Victory Blvd. CA - 95776",
"6456 rosemade ave. CA - 91776"
]
```

in the parent component:
parent.component.ts

```
addressInput = {
parentFormControl: this.addressForm.get("address"),
autocomplete: "auto"
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-input [config]="addressInput"></app-input>
```

child.component.ts

```
@component({
selector: "app-input",
templateUrl: "./label-input.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./label-input.component.scss"],
)}

export class labelInputComponent implements OnInit{
@Input() config: LabelInputConfig;
addressOptions$ = arrOptions;
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.filteredOptions = this.parentFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
startWith("),
map((value) => this._filter(value))
);

_filter(value: string): string[] {
 const filterValue = vlaue.toLowerCase();
 return this.addressOptions$.filter((addressValue) =>
  addressValue.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
 );
}
}
```

child.component.html

```
<input
 [formControl]="config.parentFormControl"
 [matAutoComplete] = "config.autocomplete"
/>
<mat-autocomplete #auto"matAutoComplete">
 <mat-option
  *ngForm="let addressOption of filteredOptions | async"
  [value]="addressOption"
 >
  {{addressOption}}
 </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

when i start typing in the input field, instead of getting values from the array above,
i am getting list of all previously entered values to that input field. Doesn't matter if the
value exists in the arrOptions or not.

can someone please help me to fix this? I only want to see the values from arrOptions when user clicks or start typing in the input field.

Comment: Sounds like you issue may be due to the autocomplete feature of the browser. On your input control set autocomplete="off"

Answer (score 0):

maybe I can help you, I use autocomplete in anguular material in file .ts

```
myControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    {name: '123 seldom st. CA - 91746'},
    {name: '4533 Victory Blvd. CA - 95776'},
    {name: '6456 rosemade ave. CA - 91776'}
  ];

  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(user: User): string {
    return user && user.name ? user.name : '';
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

I hope this script can help you

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. however i have a counter question for your solution. the formControl in my case is in the parent component. so the parent component is sending formControl. and in the child component i am getting that formControl where this whole autocomplete logic is. in that case do i need to use myControl here or i can just use that parentFormControl?